# Should it be necessary to assign navigation properties and foreign key properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have two tables: *Status* (primary key *Sid*) and *Order* (primary key *Oid*). The relation is set so that *Sid* is a foreign key in *Order* using a column *StatusId*.

When I generate the model using EF, I get two properties in *Order* that refer to *Status*. First being the actual column (type *Nullable*, which is the foreign key). Second being the navigational property (type *virtual Status*). In *Status* I only  get one property referring to *Order* (*virtual ICollection*).

I had no reasons to suspect there was anything wrong with the setup and I haven't modified anything in the classes, I have no partial alterations and I haven't changed the T4 scripts. Everything is automagically generated from the database (no Code First).

I notice something that bother me, though. When I edit one of the orders, I set the status of it (not the id integer but the actual property). In the debugger, I'm checking that it's been set. However, then I call *SaveChanges*, those are not being stored - the database contains no update and reloading the entities produces the state before my change being entered.

At the moment I tackle the problem as follows.

```
private void Combox_Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  EditedOrder.StatusId = EditedOrder.Status.Sid;
}
```

However, that seems as a work-around hinding the real issue that I have in my code, rather than something that need to be done. My question is whether my suspicion is justified.

The property or *Order* is set by data binding to a combo box using the following XAML markup.

```
<ComboBox Name="Status"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Order.Status}"
          SelectionChanged="Combox_Changed"
          Style="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxStyle}" />
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set Status? You generally are correct though, setting the Navigation Property should be enough. To figure out the real issue, we'll need to see code that wasn't working as well

Comment: @Vlad274 Posted the markup, as requested.

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 Not sure. How do I verify that it is (or isn't)?